# Implement Synchronous and Asynchronous in Node.js

Tags: node.js

How should I implement and differentiate between Asynchronous and synchronous function in Nodejs, can't able to implement it properly?

Comment: Give an proper running example if possible

Comment: You should post what you are actually looking to do... 


https://medium.com/@tkssharma/writing-neat-asynchronous-node-js-code-with-promises-async-await-fa8d8b0bcd7c

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its pretty Simple:

Say you have a function:

```js
var resolveAfter2Seconds = function() {
  console.log("starting slow promise");
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(function() {
      resolve("slow");
      console.log("slow promise is done");
    }, 2000);
  });
};
```

If you call the function by it self like

```js
 const slow = await resolveAfter2Seconds();
 console.log(slow);
```

That would be synchronous.

To make it asynchronous you would utilize the ***async*** keyword which contain an *await* expression that pauses the execution of the async function and waits for the passed Promise's resolution, and then resumes the async function's execution and returns the resolved value.
For more details click this link [Async/await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function)

Here's an example:

```js
var start = async function() {

  // 1. Execution gets here almost instantly
  const slow = await resolveAfter2Seconds();
  console.log(slow); // 2. this runs 2 seconds after 1.

}
```

Comment: Glad i could Help!!